# How do fields not selected for in a MySQL query affect query speed for the fields I am selecting on?

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

This is a theoretical question based on an application I have.  I am wondering if there is some technical insight to be gained beyond just speed tests on my system.

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `processed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_processed` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),

) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and...

```
CREATE TABLE `file_metas` (
  `file_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `keywords` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The `file_metas` data is long text strings about each file from the files table.  Each file only has one entry in the `file_metas` table so these two tables could be combined.

I'm wondering what affect adding the long text fields to the `files` table will have on the performance of select statements done on the `files` table when I'm not selecting for `title`, `description`, or `keywords`.  I'm curious about the technical details.  Does simply having the text fields in the table slow queries not involving those fields?  How does this work in general with MySQL MyISAM tables?  Is there any good reason to keep the `file_metas` data in a separate table?